# OSError: Failed to interpret file 'name.data' as a pickle

Tags: python-3.x, compiler-errors

I am trying to loadthis file.
But, Python3 said "OSError: Failed to interpret file 'D:/USER/Downloads/wine.data' as a pickle".

How to load this file?

The code I used following this
data = np.load("D:/USER/Downloads/wine.data")

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case it was the newer version of *numpy* that caused the problem.

Try installing numpy version 1.12.0

*pip install numpy==1.12.0*

Comment: Thank you! But it can't works. And then, installed the newest version of Numpy(1.17.0), also not work.